# Layout: bottom bar + scrollview over it that start from top

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I can't find a solution for that. I managed to solve the problem of NOT overlapping the scrollview with my button+textview at the bottom, but I still can't manage to have the scrollview starting from the top of the screen rather than from just above my button.

Note that even the bottom linearlayout (button+textview) isn't exactly what I wanted. I can't find a way to have everything positioned correctly.

Eclipse is not helping either, since the text view of the xml keeps changing under my mouse, making it extremely annoying. I had to open an external editor to edit it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center|top" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_phrase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/play" />
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp" >




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_player_checkboxes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CheckBox" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you tell me how you want your lay out, or an image would be great

Comment: The new stackoverflow I see doesn't allow me to edit easily :( I hope you can see this link : http://i.imgur.com/RaOLE.png This is what I want, but with the code above, I get the three "Heading3" anchored to the below's linearlayout, instead of being anchored to the top as the image shows.

Comment: okay so you want some thing like this, the number of headings are limited to three or it will be dynamic

Comment: It's a scroll view with a Linearlayout full of checkboxes. They can be any number from 1 to 20 or even more. That's why I use a scrollview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` to your scrollview while leaving the rest of what you have already, it should start at the top and fill the screen below until it comes to linearlayout2.  (Same applies if you decide to switch to a listview as rajesh.adhi suggested)

Oh, you seem to be missing a `</RelativeLayout>` there too.

Comment: weight is only for linearlayout. it is ignored by relative layouts. AlignParentTop should do the trick, though.

Comment: Doh.  I was thinking he had the scrollview wrapped in a linearlayout, in which case it would have an effect.  Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: I think I tried to wrap the scrollview in a linearlayout, but the result was that the scrollview was overlapping the button and text at the bottom.

Comment: So, did `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` fix it for you?  If it did, click the check mark to accept the answer so everyone knows the issue is resolved.

Comment: Setting alignParentTop to true seems to do the trick. Rajesh looks ok, but I don't believe I have to change everything to achieve what I wanted.